# gcloud app deploy trying to push old code

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have an app engine flexible environment running in Python. There was a syntax error in one of the python files, so when I ran the deploy command, it failed with the error "Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED" showing me the syntax error. I went ahead and fixed the error, and when I tried to re-deploy, it still showed me the old error with the old code in the stack trace. The command i am using to deploy is this :

> gcloud app deploy --version=6

The code being pushed is getting cached somewhere and I am unable to figure out how to clear the cache. I am using gcloudignore file and its content are as follows :

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
__pycache__/
/setup.cfg
```

EDIT : My app.yaml file is as follows :

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 3600

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: ai4sg-armman:asia-south1:mmitra-armaan-10gb-cloudsql,ai4sg-armman:asia-south1:mmitra-predictions

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 8
  memory_gb: 45
  disk_size_gb: 1000
```

The full terminal logs can be found here : https://justpaste.it/4y1px

Comment: The error is very general, it is necessary to have more details about it, so, add this --verbosity=debug at the end of your gcloud command and share the results. In addition, share your app.yaml file in order to look at it.

Comment: Added app.yaml file. Ran it with verbosity=debug. Here are the logs : https://justpaste.it/4y1px

Comment: Deploying to a new version solves the issue. But it will still be useful to know how to clear the cache for the same version.

Comment: I am facing this issue again where my static JS files are not getting deployed. I also tried deploying to a new version of appengine but that did not work either. Debug logs can be found at https://justpaste.it/4y1px

Comment: The logs in both links you shared do not contain too many other details. From where you are trying to deploy? From local, from cloud shell, from a VM? Are you using Cloud Build or something else here? Since there is not enough information here, it could be a better idea to open a support case in order to take a look at your project