# Why is google cloud app deploy still giving me the old site

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment

Recently I update all my site to a new node.js version 13.
I work hard to fixed everything. (My old site was online on Google cloud over 1 year with a version 7 or 8 and was working).
So I create my dist folder, and I create a new bucket on Google cloud. I follow every step from this site:

https://medium.com/@hb.ui/deploy-angular-app-to-google-cloud-app-engine-bucket-storage-9a9852f29869

So my new site was working fine with the new look.

But I had some small mistakes in some pages, so I rebuild a new dist folder. I erase the dist folder in my bucket and upload the new one.

I redo these 2 steps (with my real site name):

```
gsutil rsync -r gs://fitness-dashboard-bucket ./fitness-dashboard-app
```

and

```
gcloud app deploy ./fitness-dashboard-app
```

Unfortunately, the deploy gives me the old site. I modify and update the YAML file like it says in this post:

[gcloud app deploy trying to push old code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259148/gcloud-app-deploy-trying-to-push-old-code)

And the site was not working . (GREAT,  so I know that the deploy is working). I resend my real yaml file and do the 2 commands. but the site still giving me the old site again.

Why my modification are not taken ? Does I need to versioning ? If so How I do this ?

How I can update my site  ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it by myself.

I Open Editor in google and I saw old directories from a previous deployment. Like if the dist folder was not the same.

So I erase all old stuff in my app directory.

I close the editor and return to the terminal.

I just sync again et redeploy and finally I got my new site.

(I use my 2 commands that I write in my question to sync and deploy).